# Como configurar o pygame em português?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Estou fazendo um jogo com pygame. Eu quero mostrar um texto em português na tela, mas o mesmo troca "ç", "ã", "[", e "<" por "?" (ponto de interrogação).

```
import pygame
class TelaInicial():
    def __init__(self, logoTipo = None, lagura_do_logo_tipo = None, altura_do_logo_tipo = None, posicao_x_do_logo_tipo = None, posicao_y_do_logo_tipo = None):
        self.altura_do_logo_tipo = 350
        self.lagura_do_logo_tipo = 250
        self.posicao_x_do_logo_tipo = pygame.display.Info().current_w - 700
        self.posicao_y_do_logo_tipo = pygame.display.Info().current_h - 450
        self.logoTipo = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('./imagens/logo-tipo.png'), (self.lagura_do_logo_tipo, self.altura_do_logo_tipo))

    def logo_tipo(self, tela):
        tela.blit(self.logoTipo, (self.posicao_x_do_logo_tipo, self.posicao_y_do_logo_tipo))

    def aperteEspaco(self, tela):
        font = pygame.font.Font("./fonts/smbfont.ttf", 45)
        texto = font.render("APERTE ESPAÇO", True, (255, 255, 255))
        tela.blit(texto, (pygame.display.Info().current_w - 700, pygame.display.Info().current_h - 80))

    def background(self):
        pass
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Coloque realmente o seu código e não um print do mesmo, explique melhor a sua pergunta já que ela esta muito ampla, e deixe explicito o ponto ao qual você teve dificuldade.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se os símbolos aparecem como `?` isso simplesmente significa que o arquivo de fontes que você está usando - `smbfont.ttf` não inclui esses símbolos  -e eles são substituídos por "?".

Esse é um problema muito comum com fontes de baixa qualidade, como as que eram distribuidas aos milhares em CD-ROMs em bancas de revista nas décadas de 90 e 2000.

Quando se usa uma fonte num aplicativo "normal" do sistema operacional, o próprio sistema se encarrega de fazer essa substituição, quando é assim. No Pygame, o controle é mais manual - tem-se que fazer tudo na mão. Infelizmente, a API que o Pygame apresenta não permite introspecção nas fontes carregadas para saber se um símbolo existe ou não.

Esse tipo de erro de acentuação e etc... é comum em aplicações que usam o terminal (cmd) no Windows, ou aplicações em Pygame usando Python 2, por conta de codificações de texto diferentes (ex. "utf-8", "CP1252", etc...) - mas em Python3, em que o texto do programa é todo tratado como Unicode, esse problema não existe mais - usando Pygame, se um caractere existe na fonte que você está usando, ele será desenhado corretamente.

Resumindo: o que vai arrumar a coisa pra você é usar uma fonte que inclua os caracteres acentuados e símbolos, além de só as letras maiúsculas. Eu recomendo que você olhe as fontes que o Google disponibiliza em https://fonts.google.com/ : são todas de uso permitido e de altíssima qualidade (só é um pouco chato navegar até conseguir baixar as mesmas como um arquivo TTF, mas é possível)

Answer (score 2):

Tente especificar uma fonte, em vez da que você está usando (você está usando o padrão?) - é mais provável que seja um problema na fonte.

**Palavras do autor original**

> - Funcionou para mim com todas as fontes que eu tentei no meu sistema.

Para jogos completos, uma solução ideal é distribuir o arquivo de fonte ao lado do seu projeto - já que as fontes abertas do Pygame recebem o nome de arquivo ".ttf".

Para usar uma fonte do sistema, você tem que encadear chamadas `pygame.font.get_fonts()`  para obter nomes de fontes, para `pygame.font.match_font` para obter o caminho para o arquivo de fonte dado o nome da fonte e, finalmente, `pygame.font`. Fonte passando esse caminho e um tamanho de ponto para obter um objeto de fonte utilizável (com o método de renderização)

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165158/pygame-font-render-cropping-uppercase-letters-with-acute-accents-tilde-or-cir)

## Problemas semelhantes

[Rendering unicode in pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31942122/rendering-unicode-in-pygame)

[Rendering unicode font with pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37912979/rendering-unicode-font-with-pygame?rq=1)

Comment: Obrigaod por citar minha resposta lá - mas infelizmente o problema aque é outro - o A.P. já não está usando a fonte original.

Answer (score -1):

Olhei em um código que eu tenho e simplesmente adicionando no Unicode no início do código e iniciando a fonte ela apresenta os caracteres normalmente.

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-


#Init the font module
        pygame.font.init()
        #Instance of Font
        font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 25)
```

Comment: Essa declaração não é necessária em Python 3. Mas ela nunca fez nenhuma mágica - ela só avisa o complador do Python sobre a codificação de acentuação usada no próprio arqiuvo em que ela aparece. Se estivesse faltando isso, (em Python 2), o autor do código teria tido um erro de sintaxe, não caracteres incorretos.